# Loggin in php not working

Tags: php, error-logging

i am new to php and i am trying to make a register and log in page.

When I register as a new user it works fine and comes up in the database.However, when it comes to logging in there seems to be a problem that i tried everything.

what i want to do is when a user logs in, it redirect them to the home page, and if the log in information was wrong then it would show an error message.

Here is the php code that is in the log in file:

```
    <?php

session_start();

if( isset($_SESSION['users_id'])    ){
    header("Location: /");
}

require 'database.php';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,email,password FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $message = '';

    if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])  )
    {
        $_SESSION['users_id'] = $results['id'];
        header("Location: php.dev/index.php", true, 301);   exit();
    } 
    else {
        $message = 'Sorry, thoes credentials do not match';
    }

endif;

?>
```

the `header("Location:....)` this doesn't seem to work. i'm really stuck here any help ?

Here is the html code:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link href="Style/phpstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
    <a href="php.dev/index.php"> TIPBUCKET </a>
</div>

<?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
    <p><?= $message ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<h1>Login</h1>

<span> or <a href="register.php">Register here</a></span>

<form action="login.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email">

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">

<input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is what happens when i log in]

Thank you in advance to any replies :)

Comment: What is `php.dev/index.php` meant to be? Certainly that is not a URL...

Comment: i'm using a local host MAMP, so the current url is php.dev and index.php is the home page

Comment: A valid URL would be `http://php.dev/index.php`. `php.dev/index.php` is just some arbitrary string with dots and a slash in it.

Comment: you should probably post the html form for this and db schema. it could be anything from something to do with the form (inputs, method, etc.) and/or right up to the password column's length not being long enough. Value for one password is what? check for errors with php's error reporting and error handling on PDO.

Comment: you're probably also outputting before header. Use error reporting then come back and tell us what the error is, if any.

Comment: i just posted the html code. the inputs and methods seem to be correct

Comment: is it showing anything in the browser? what do you see when you login?

Comment: what is the result of `$records->execute();` and `$results`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It shows the the else code. and not really redirecting to the home page.

Comment: [*My comment here...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896236/loggin-in-php-not-working#comment67078517_39896236) wasn't fully answered. If I don't know what those are, then I can't help any further with this question. You will need to post any errors you may have (if you're checking for them) and there are 2. Again: error reporting and PDO's error handling. Password column length is what; 60+ I hope? If it isn't and is anything less than 60, then your query is failing on you "silently". I would also just use `SELECT password` instead of `SELECT id,email,password`.

Comment: @user3719086  
is it showing anything in the browser? what do you see when you login?

Comment: @user3719086 could it be that your register code if messing up

Comment: @user3718086 i just posted a screen shot of what happens when i log in

Comment: @Thomas the register page work fine it connects to the database and all. its just when i added a redirector (header) to the code it just does not work.

Comment: @user3719086 `var_dump($results);` and see what it shows

Comment: @NeelIon where do i add that ?

Comment: @user3719086 after `$results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @user3719086 shows anything?

Comment: this what it shows on top of the page.

Comment: array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["email"]=> string(19) "ibrahim@ibrahim.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$jGNLebrOKKl57SxmdRM92.JgWQ4VIEj8QFEA5tZ7gSTOjSPeYcAxq" }

Comment: @NeelIon that what it shows ^^^

Comment: @user3719086 are you sure you are using correct credentials? please reset your password and email and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your header:

```
header("Location: php.dev/index.php", ture, 301);
```

should be

```
 header("Location: php.dev/index.php", true, 301);
```

Comment: Good eyes. But still the same thing happens

Comment: some how it skips the "if{count($results)............}" and goes to the "else{$message...... }" line and just shows ' Sorry, thoes credentials do not match '

Comment: Can you also post the password_verify function ? It may be the source of your problems (as it skip the if statement)

Comment: @BananasSplitter `password_verify` is built-in http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php